# How to replace a commit with a commit history?

Tags: git

I am working on a repository that someone copied from an initial repository. Rather than just forking the repo, he copied the files and made a new repo out of it. He worked on it and I cannot lose his commits. I forked his repository but now I still have this 'first commit'. I would like to rewrite this commit with the commit history from the initial repository that should have been forked.

Comment: _However, I would like to get the history back from the initial repository?_, the forked repository should have all the history of it's parent repository in context of GitHub

Comment: I have rewritten the description of the problem, since it contained a mistake. The situation is a little different. The repo was copied instead of forked.

Comment: In Git, the history in a repository *is* the commits in the repository. Put commits in and you add more history. That's all there is to it: two repositories that contain the same commits have the same history; two repositories with different commits have different history. To see if you have the same commits, examine the commit *hashes* as those are the true names of each commit.

Comment: @FOR_SCIENCE, I have added an answer since you edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Saurabh P Bhandari is right. But if you want to reset your repo to forked. To be the same without that initial commit:

You can use `upstream` as the remote name referencing the original repo forked:

```
git remote add upstream /url/to/original/repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master  
git push origin master --force
```

Comment: I made a mistake in describing the problem. The description is now rewritten. The repo was not forked but copied. Read the description for the full details.

Answer (score 0):

A - initial repository

B -  repository which you forked (*I forked his repository but now I still have this 'first commit'*)

If you intend to update A with the changes done in B, you can do the following in A

Add B as remote in A

```
git remote add B <repoB-url>
```

Fetch B in A

```
git fetch B
```

Merge B

```
git merge B/<branch-name> --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Instead of fetch and merge you can directly do a pull

```
git pull B <branch-name> --allow-unrelated-histories
```